# How to output one screen at a time in Perl

Tags: perl, screen

When executing a Perl script from the command line, how can I ensure that my output doesn't scroll off the screen?

In other words, how do I mimic the functionality of the Unix [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command)) or [less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)) commands?

Answer (score 6):

The [Term::Pager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::Pager) module would seem to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The user can just pipe the output to `less`. That gives them the option of using their favourite pager, or even not using any pager at all, if they prefer that.

Comment: Perhaps the script is interactive at certain points, but the author wants to display a block of text (an EULA or long warning message for example) - piping would not work as expected in this case.

Comment: First check $PAGER environment variable. /bin/more and /usr/bin/less are two safe fallback options.

Comment: @Gavin Brock: In that case, I'd definitely like to be able to pipe the output, so that I can pipe the EULA to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 1):

As [Matti Virkkunen says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940586/how-to-output-one-screen-at-a-time-in-perl/2940590#2940590), it's better that the user pipes your script to `less`.

A user of a Unix-like system would expect output in plain text, so (s)he can pipe it to other commands if they need to. Making your script not displaying output as plain text, your user may find your script less usable.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick-and-dirty way, you can pipe the text to *less* or *more*:

```
my $text = <<'EOD';
Lots
   and
      lots
         of
           text
EOD

my $pager = $ENV{PAGER} || 'less';
open(my $less, '|-', $pager, '-e') || die "Cannot pipe to $pager: $!";
print $less $text;
close($less);
```

There are various *less* and *more* flags to allow the script to continue when it reaches the bottom of the text.

Comment: It would be much better to use lexical filehandles, and check the user's PAGER environment variable to see if they have a preference over `less`.

Comment: Updated the code. I guess the use of $ENV{PAGER} adds risk that the user can break the script with a messed up environment.